# Lazy filter depending on the previous line (Polars Python)

Tags: python-polars

I'm using Python Polars and I have a table like this :

| Column1 | Column2 |
| --- | --- |
| id1 | 1 |
| id1 | 1 |
| id1 | 2 |
| id1 | 1 |
| id1 | 1 |
| id1 | 2 |
| id1 | 3 |

I would like, using Polars Lazy API, to have the result when column2 previous element is different from the actual column2 element. So the result would look like this after the operation :

| Column1 | Column2 |
| --- | --- |
| id1 | 1 |
| id1 | 2 |
| id1 | 1 |
| id1 | 2 |
| id1 | 3 |

Thanks !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let me elaborate on how `shift` and `shift_and_fill` work.  The use of these comes down to strategy (and knowing your data).

**Using `shift`**

Let's start with this data set:

```py
import polars as pl
df = pl.DataFrame({"row_num": range(1, 8),
                   "Column2": [1, 2, 3, 3, 4, 5, 4]}).lazy()
df.collect()
```

```
shape: (7, 2)
┌─────────┬─────────┐
│ row_num ┆ Column2 │
│ ---     ┆ ---     │
│ i64     ┆ i64     │
╞═════════╪═════════╡
│ 1       ┆ 1       │
├╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ 2       ┆ 2       │
├╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ 3       ┆ 3       │
├╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ 4       ┆ 3       │
├╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ 5       ┆ 4       │
├╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ 6       ┆ 5       │
├╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ 7       ┆ 4       │
└─────────┴─────────┘
```

Now, let's create intermediate columns to see how these functions work.

```py
(df
    .with_column(pl.col("Column2").shift().alias("Column2_shifted"))
    .with_column((pl.col("Column2") != pl.col("Column2_shifted")).alias("not_eq_result"))
).collect()
```

```
shape: (7, 4)
┌─────────┬─────────┬─────────────────┬───────────────┐
│ row_num ┆ Column2 ┆ Column2_shifted ┆ not_eq_result │
│ ---     ┆ ---     ┆ ---             ┆ ---           │
│ i64     ┆ i64     ┆ i64             ┆ bool          │
╞═════════╪═════════╪═════════════════╪═══════════════╡
│ 1       ┆ 1       ┆ null            ┆ true          │
├╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ 2       ┆ 2       ┆ 1               ┆ true          │
├╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ 3       ┆ 3       ┆ 2               ┆ true          │
├╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ 4       ┆ 3       ┆ 3               ┆ false         │
├╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ 5       ┆ 4       ┆ 3               ┆ true          │
├╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ 6       ┆ 5       ┆ 4               ┆ true          │
├╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ 7       ┆ 4       ┆ 5               ┆ true          │
└─────────┴─────────┴─────────────────┴───────────────┘
```

Notice how in the first row, the `Column2_shifted` has a `null` (really, `None`) value in the first row.

But more importantly, the result of `(pl.col("Column2") != pl.col("Column2_shifted"))` is `True` for the first row.

Thus, as long as `null` values are not allowed in `Column2`, the first row **will** be included.  You don't need to separately concatenate the first row of the dataset to your results.

Note: in practice, you don't need these intermediate columns.  You can simply use `.filter(pl.col("Column2") != pl.col("Column2").shift())`.  The intermediate columns are just for explanatory purposes here.

**Using `shift_and_fill`**

If `None`/`null` values are allowed in `Column2`, then you can try using `shift_and_fill` and selecting a `fill_value` that is not allowed in `Column2`.

For example, if you know that negative numbers are not allowed in `Column2`, you can use this logic.

```py
(df
    .with_column(pl.col("Column2").shift_and_fill(periods=1, fill_value=-1).alias("Column2_shifted"))
    .with_column((pl.col("Column2") != pl.col("Column2_shifted")).alias("not_eq_result"))
).collect()
```

```
shape: (7, 4)
┌─────────┬─────────┬─────────────────┬───────────────┐
│ row_num ┆ Column2 ┆ Column2_shifted ┆ not_eq_result │
│ ---     ┆ ---     ┆ ---             ┆ ---           │
│ i64     ┆ i64     ┆ i64             ┆ bool          │
╞═════════╪═════════╪═════════════════╪═══════════════╡
│ 1       ┆ 1       ┆ -1              ┆ true          │
├╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ 2       ┆ 2       ┆ 1               ┆ true          │
├╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ 3       ┆ 3       ┆ 2               ┆ true          │
├╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ 4       ┆ 3       ┆ 3               ┆ false         │
├╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ 5       ┆ 4       ┆ 3               ┆ true          │
├╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ 6       ┆ 5       ┆ 4               ┆ true          │
├╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ 7       ┆ 4       ┆ 5               ┆ true          │
└─────────┴─────────┴─────────────────┴───────────────┘
```

With this strategy, the first row is always included, without having to separately concatenate the first row to your results.  That's because you've purposely selected a `fill_value` that will never match any value in `Column2`.

**Adding `is_first` to the expression**

If you are unsure of which values are allowed in `Column2` (even `None`), then I would suggest appending `is_first` to your expression (rather than concatenating the first row to your results dataset):

```py
(df
    .with_column(pl.col("Column2").shift().alias("Column2_shifted"))
    .with_column((pl.col("Column2").is_first() | (pl.col("Column2") != pl.col("Column2_shifted"))).alias("not_eq_result"))
).collect()
```

```
shape: (7, 4)
┌─────────┬─────────┬─────────────────┬───────────────┐
│ row_num ┆ Column2 ┆ Column2_shifted ┆ not_eq_result │
│ ---     ┆ ---     ┆ ---             ┆ ---           │
│ i64     ┆ i64     ┆ i64             ┆ bool          │
╞═════════╪═════════╪═════════════════╪═══════════════╡
│ 1       ┆ 1       ┆ null            ┆ true          │
├╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ 2       ┆ 2       ┆ 1               ┆ true          │
├╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ 3       ┆ 3       ┆ 2               ┆ true          │
├╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ 4       ┆ 3       ┆ 3               ┆ false         │
├╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ 5       ┆ 4       ┆ 3               ┆ true          │
├╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ 6       ┆ 5       ┆ 4               ┆ true          │
├╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ 7       ┆ 4       ┆ 5               ┆ true          │
└─────────┴─────────┴─────────────────┴───────────────┘
```

This forces your first row to evaluate to `True`, simply because it is first.  (Just be **very** careful with the nested paratheses in the expression - or you may not get the result you expect.

Does this help clarify things?

Comment: Oh yeah I understand now why it doesn't took up the first row. To be honest, I totally forgot about that `is_first()` function. I should give more look at the docs. Thanks for your time and explanations !

Answer (score 1):

Use the `shift` expression.

```py
import polars as pl

df = pl.DataFrame(
    {"Column1": ["id1"] * 7, "Column2": [1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 2, 3]}).lazy()

df.filter(pl.col("Column2") != pl.col("Column2").shift(periods=1)).collect()
```

```
shape: (5, 2)
┌─────────┬─────────┐
│ Column1 ┆ Column2 │
│ ---     ┆ ---     │
│ str     ┆ i64     │
╞═════════╪═════════╡
│ id1     ┆ 1       │
├╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ id1     ┆ 2       │
├╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ id1     ┆ 1       │
├╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ id1     ┆ 2       │
├╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ id1     ┆ 3       │
└─────────┴─────────┘
```

You can find documentation about the options here:
https://pola-rs.github.io/polars/py-polars/html/reference/api/polars.Expr.shift.html#polars.Expr.shift

Note that you can reverse the direction of the shift as well as the count using the `periods` argument.

And there is also a version `shift_and_fill` that will fill the `None` values created as a result of the shift.

Comment: This solution work but it will always miss one result (depending if periods is 1 or -1 then the head or tail will not be count in the result). So I just added before the filter, a save of the first row with `first = lazyFrame.first()` then after the filter, I just use `polars.concat` with first and lazyFrame and it gives me the expected result, thanks !

Comment: Actually, you may not need to do this.  Indeed, you may accidentally create a duplicate record by concatenating the first record to your results.  I've elaborated on my answer.  I hope this helps.